# AES-XTS Integrity protection

Tags: aes, xts

AES-XTS does not guarantee data integrity, like AES-GCM for instance. So, in order to support data integrity it is necessary to add some MAC functionality to it. However, adding an independent MAC, for instance like HMAC, requires additional calculations over the whole encrypted block. Is there a standard way to calculate a MAC over AES-XTS block in a more efficient way?

Comment: Why are you concerned with ‘another pass’?  AES-GCM involves ‘two passes’, but they can be pipelined because the GHASH pass does not require all of the AES-CTR pass to have completed—you can go block by block with CTR-then-GHASH.  (In contrast, _e.g._, AES-GCM-SIV has to hash the plaintext first before it can start encrypting.)  Are you concerned with _performance_, and worried that ‘two passes’ is a _proxy_ for it, or are you actually worried about ‘two passes’ as a design principle?  AES itself breaks down into many rounds—would it become a (say) 15-pass system if we looked at it that way?

Comment: Why do you want to get an authenticated cipher out of AES-XTS?  The usual application of AES-XTS is disk encryption, which necessarily preserves the size of a disk sector so there's no room for an authentication tag in the first place.  Why don't you just use AES-GCM if you want an authenticated cipher that uses AES, or AES-GCM-SIV if you also want it to be nonce-misuse-resistant?  What's the importance of AES-XTS?  (In principle, you could do GHASH over AES-XTS and get something like AES-GCM but with AES-XTS instead of AES-CTR underneath—however, the performance would be worse than AES-GCM.)

Comment: You should talk about the attack types or your security risks. AES-GCM or AES-XTS with HMAC doesn't prevent the rollback attack in which the attacker can replace the new data with the old one.

Comment: I concerned with performance, and 2 path is a proxy for that. My problem with using GCM is that essentially it is counter mode, and as such, I must use a different IV each time I write data, and this IV has to be managed and preserved. In XTS I do not have to deal with IV. However, its important for me to control the integrity, which I do have in GCM, but do not have with XTS.  Re rollback attack, this has to be managed in some other way, neither GCM nor XTS can countermeasure this, to the best of my knowledge

Comment: If you're concerned with performance, what measurements have you taken to confirm that, for example, AES-GCM-SIV is too costly for your purposes?

Comment: As a matter of fact I did not calculate the exact performance figure of GCM. I do not have a room for the IV of GCM, which is not required in XTS

Comment: Some useful information: [dm-crypt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/device-mapper/dm-crypt.html) and [dm-integrity](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/device-mapper/dm-integrity.html) kernel documentation.

Comment: In AES-XTS, you specify a tweak—typically a disk sector number, in disk encryption.  You can use what you _would have_ used for the AES-XTS tweak as the AES-GCM-SIV nonce without storing anything.  If you never _rewrite_ a disk sector—that is, if you never reuse a disk sector number (_e.g._, if this is a log-structured disk, for instance, and you just count up logical ‘sector’ numbers indefinitely)—then you can also use it this as the nonce for AES-GCM.  But note that the authenticated ciphertext is necessarily larger than the plaintext _no matter what_ authenticated cipher you use.

Comment: As an in between, you could try a wide-block mode like EME. That doesn't provide true integrity, but it's far less malleable than XTS (full sector-sized randomization on a single bit flip rather than 16 byte). It's of course a much better idea to use AEAD, but if you really, really need a setup with zero overhead for MAC tags, a wide-block mode is the way to go.

Comment: Please consider ALL OTHER ALTERNATIVES first before praying that your upper layers of software will behave reasonably on garbage data, which is simply a bad idea.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I understand XTS is used for disk encryption hence limiting disk usage (not storing authentication tags) is a requirement... but does that mean FileVault and VeraCrypt are vulnerable to tampering such as evil maid attacks? In other words, how can we know our backups have not been tampered with? Is considering that attack vector important in the first place?